# Pure css drop down menu without js ( if js is disabled) in IE 6?

Tags: css, accessibility

I found many css/js menu scripts on various sites they work well is in FF, IE7 and safari, opera if JS is disabled but not in IE 6 and for IE 6 small js file need to add because IE doesnt support hover but my question is can we make pre css dropdown menu for IE6 because 
IE 6 support :hover on  then can we make dropw down menu without javascript for IE6 and all other browsers. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only legit non-JS workaround albeit nasty is using conditionals and a `table` element:

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html

Edit:

Actually there appears to be a new method from Stu which relies on a huge margin offset, plenty of explicit stacking order declarations, I think he's using some kind of float drop.

Seems to have been pioneered by either Paul O'B/Timo @ http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=635116&page=5

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/new-dropdown.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not really feasible in IE6, because while IE6 supports :hover, it only supports it on link elements, nothing else. You could fall back to CSS expressions, but at that point you're essentially sending some custom Javascript to IE6, and CSS expressions tend to leak memory like nobody's business.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a CSS only solution like the one written by [Steve Gibson](http://www.grc.com/menu2/invitro.htm) of GRC.